# SharePoint 2010 - Issue with trusted domains

Tags: access-denied, trusted-domain

I have a domain trust between the domain where my SP2010 server lives and another domain.  We have successfully added them to SP Permissions and also to the Profile synchronization.  What happens is that intermittently they are not able to log in and get an access denied.  This also occurs after they have accessed the pages, but then it requires them to re-authenticate after about 20 minutes. They have this issue the most when they have an opened file from the SP site.  It doesn't happen all the time.  The events log on the server shows a

```
Subject:
                Security ID:                       NULL SID
                Account Name:                     -
                Account Domain:                 -
                Logon ID:                               0x0

Logon Type:                                          3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
                Security ID:                      NULL SID
                Account Name:                     AAAAA
                Account Domain:                 XXXNETWORK

Failure Information:
                Failure Reason:                An Error occured during Logon.
                Status:                                0xc000005e
                Sub Status:                             0x0

Process Information:
                Caller Process ID:  0x0
                Caller Process Name:            -

Network Information:
                Workstation Name:              AAAAA03
                Source Network Address:    10.10.2.234
                Source Port:                    62370

Detailed Authentication Information:
                Logon Process:                     NtLmSsp 
                Authentication Package:     NTLM
                Transited Services:                -
                Package Name (NTLM only):              -
                Key Length:                           0
```

Answer (score 0):

error code 0*c000005e means "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request". are you using the Kerberos Authentication, typically it is related to Kerberos.

You have to add the correct SPN...even not Kerberos then

> Now this seems strange as my farm is not running Kerberos and nor are
>   the Web Applications so I could have quite easily discarded the blog
>   however stranger things have happened so I followed the blog mentioned
>   and added a Kerberos SPN for the farm account to AD.

Read more: [User Profile Synchronization Service failed to start due to Kerberos issue](http://www.paulgrimley.com/2011/06/user-profile-synchronization-service.html)

Also have a look http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2010/08/12/